# Login redirect problem

Tags: redirect, login

hey i got a slightly weird problem..

i got a form enabling login in certain single's according to the cateory and user level.. it works great but the server which is windows (where the website is hosted on returns the wrong "current page" value

Meaning.. this:

```
'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ),
```

returns this:
www.somewebsite.com/sub/sub/?p=100

instead of:
www.somewebsite.com/sub/?p=100

**This is the actuall form:**

> ```
>           <div class="logincategory">
>             <?php wp_login_form( $args );
>              $args = array(
>             'echo' => true,
>             'redirect' => site_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),
>             'form_id' => 'loginform',
>             'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
>             'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
>             'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
>             'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
>             'id_username' => 'user_login',
>             'id_password' => 'user_pass',
>             'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
>             'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
>             'remember' => true,
>             'value_username' => NULL,
>             'value_remember' => false ); ?> 
>             </div>
> ```
>
> **So..**
>   this is a bug of the server which i can't solve directly

**so i used**

> $myCurrentUrl = site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); 
>   $myCurrentUrltwo = str_replace("www.somewebsite.com/sub/sub/","www.somewebsite.com/sub/", "$myCurrentUrl");

That (when eching) returns the right URL but how do i insert
the variable into this command

```
    'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ),
```

Comment: having the exact same issue.

Comment: i made a hacky solution.. i have created a folder on my root hosting with the same name as the the folder that is being shown up twice then put an index.php file inside of it with the code in my answer down here (the header(status...) answer i wrote here - so i hope it would help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the changes seen in the diff on this trac ticket:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/17243

i've adjusted my redirect to the following

```
'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

and this seems to work for WP when it is in a subfolder.  this will be the new default value starting in WP 3.3 and wp_login_form() works for me in 3.3-beta3 without passing any arguments.

so for now i am going to serve up arguments conditionally based on version (maybe overkill)

```
if ( !version_compare( $wp_version, '3.3-beta3', '>=' ) ) {
    $args = array ( 'redirect' => ( is_ssl() ? 'https://' : 'http://' ) . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
} else {
    $args = array ();
} 

wp_login_form($args);
```

Comment: 10x for your help.. that ticket gave the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

change your redirect to:

```
'redirect' => '/' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
```

That will then take you to the right location.

Comment: Noep that still takes me to the wrong place...

This : $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return the wrong address.. i need to change this with my varible..

Comment: What does $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] return?

Comment: www.somewebsite.com/sub/sub/?p=100
(for example)..

instead of:
www.somewebsite.com/sub/?p=100

Its a server error and not a problem with wordpress..
is there any way to feed 'redirect' a value from a variable ??

Comment: what does it return outside of the site_url() function?

Comment: What do you mean? "outside of the site_url() function?"

I treid writing everything in my inital explenation..

Comment: try the redirect without the site_url function as in my answer (which I just edited)

Comment: i did alex. thanks for your help but it creates the sub folder name twice..  i dont get it .. just a never ending problem i guess 

the website redirects like this:
www.somewebsite.com/subFolder/subFOlder/somepage...

instead of:
www.somewebsite.com/subFolder/

Answer (score 0):

Insert it like this:

```
<?php wp_login_form( $args );
             $args = array(
            'echo' => true,
            'redirect' => $myCurrentUrltwo,
            'form_id' => 'loginform',
            'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
            'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
            'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
            'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
            'id_username' => 'user_login',
            'id_password' => 'user_pass',
            'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
            'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
            'remember' => true,
            'value_username' => NULL,
            'value_remember' => false ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried that.. i guess the server reWrited on the way to the browser.
thanks for all you help.. guys.. i solved it using this:

```
<?php
header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /sub/index.php?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
exit;
?>
```

That works so i am going to stay with that since the client needed a fast solution.